# Converter variável enum para int em C#

Tags: c#, enums, int

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
enum type = { OPEN = 0, CLOSED, UNDEFINED};
list<int> frequencia = new list<int>(new int[] {0,0,0});
```

Gostaria posteriormente de realizar a seguinte operação:

```
type t = enum.OPEN;
frequencia[t]++;
```

mas não consigo. Alguma solução em como converter a variável enum para int?

Comment: É só fazer um type-cast: `(int)enumValue`.

Comment: Em C# o padrão de codificação é usar "Open, Closed, Undefined" sem ALL CAPS.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo, era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Obrigado!

Comment: @bigdown, obrigado pela dica. Vou adotá-la.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
int t = (int)enum.OPEN;
frequencia[t]++;
```